# Sum occurrences of a specific type with start and end position

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is it possible to create some kind of summary table like this:

**Output**

```
 Type   StartPos    EndPos
 A      1           1
 B      2           3
 A      4           7
 B      8           9  
 A      10          15
```

...from data like this:

**Input**

```
Nr  Name    Type
1   Foo1    A
2   Foo2    B
3   Foo3    B
4   Foo4    A
5   Foo5    A
6   Foo6    A
7   Foo7    A
8   Foo8    B
9   Foo9    B
10  Foo10   A
11  Foo11   A
12  Foo12   A
13  Foo13   A
14  Foo14   A
15  Foo15   A
```

...where occurrences of "Type" ar summed (with start and end position) until the next Type occurs.

Any help, ideas or pointers are very much appreciated!

Comment: I'm not aware of any native methods in Excel to accomplish something like that. You'll probably have to write a macro function to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your original table is in A1:C16 (with headers in row 1), enter *Type*, *StartPos* and *EndPos* in E1, F1 and G1 respectively.

Then enter this formula in D1:

=SUMPRODUCT(0+($C$2:$C$16<>$C$3:$C$17))

Then this **array formula**** in G2:

=IF(ROWS($1:1)>$D$1,"",SMALL(IF($C$2:$C$16<>$C$3:$C$17,ROW($C$2:$C$16)-MIN(ROW($C$2:$C$16))+1),ROWS($1:1)))

Copy this formula down (though not the one in D1 - that's a one-off) until you start to get blanks for the results.

Then this (non-array) formula in F2:

=IF(ROWS($1:1)=1,1,IF(G2="","",G1+1))

Then this (non-array) formula in E2:

=IF(F2="","",IF(ROWS($1:1)=1,$C$2,IF(E1="A","B","A")))

Again, copy both these down as required.

Note that, since your example featured no *Type* data other than "A" or "B", and you didn't mention whether there indeed could be such data, I have not accounted for such a possibility in the above set-up, and have "hard-coded" these two values into one of the formulas.

Note also that the values in columns F and G are not derived from your entries in the *Nr* column (I don't see the relevance of this data, unless it's simply a listing of integers from 1 onwards) but are the *relative* row numbers within the table at each change in *StartPos*/*EndPos*.

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*

Comment: Thank you for answering, but when entering the array formula in G2, I get a "The formula you typed contains an error" message (I'm using Ctrl-Shift as you're supposed to). I've been trying to split your promising formula in parts and make it work that way (and build up some understanding in what it is you're trying to do in each step), but I haven't succeeded yet. Could you please check that the formulas you entered are corect and working? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you're using a version of Excel for which the argument separator in formulas is not the comma but the semi-colon?

Comment: You're right about the argument separator. I had discovered it myself but only for the IF statements (stupid me). Now about your solution: it's absolutely awesome! I've been struggling with macros and stuff, but this is great. Thanks A LOT!